# How to have a longer http timeout in Go using ArangoDB driver?

Tags: http, go, arangodb

I want to execute a pretty big query on an ArangoDB server, when I execute the query on the ArangoDB server itself without using Go it takes 140 seconds. But when I want to execute the query I get a http gateway timeout:

```
Unsupported content type 'text/html' with status 504 and content '<html>
<head><title>504 Gateway Time-out</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>504 Gateway Time-out</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.19.0</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I already tried using a timeout from context but it doesn't solve the job.

What I tried was:

```
ctx := driver.WithQueryCount(context.Background())
timeContext, cancel := context.WithTimeout(ctx, 5*60*1000*time.Millisecond)
defer cancel()
db, err := c.Database(timeContext, internalDatabase)
```

How can this be solved?

Comment: I'm not familiar with ArangoDB, but it's daemon runs on ports 8529, 8530 tcp. NGINX usually runs on ports 80, 443 tcp. What makes you believe, that the shown webserver 504 is the answer to a database call?

Comment: @MichaelD. because I create a connection first with http.NewConnection and I can create a connection, client and a database in Go but when I want to create the cursor it takes ages and then I get that error message while using the timeContext I created. And with other queries that don't take that much time everything goes fine.